# I am trying to get a file to read in to an Array list but im havin some troubles

Tags: file, arraylist

I am trying to get a file to read into an Arraylist, read me back the numbers in the file and calculate the average of the numbers is the file. I have tried several different types of code but have had no success. here is my code. IF anyone could please just tell me what the code has wrong with it and show me how to fix it i would greatly appreciate it.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
//import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
//import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
//import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Week07 {


    public static void main(String []args) throws IOException
    {
            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            int a = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
            //check result
             File file = null;
                if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                }
                return;
        }
        File file;

        ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();{
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {

            String text = null;
            while ((text = br.readLine()) != null) {
                values.add(text);
            }

        } catch (IOException exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();}
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Numbers are :" + values);
        }}
```

Comment: what is the specific problem that you are having? what doesn't work?

Comment: When I run the program it open the file chooser but once the file is selected it terminates the program

Answer (score 0):

You are returning after the file is choosed, check the `return` in the code below

```
                File file = null;
                if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                }
                return;
```

change that code do this:

```
            File file = null;
            if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            }
            if(file==null){
               return;//only return if no file was choosed
            }
```